# Disable / hide Google Fusion Tables infowindow by css

Tags: dictionary, google-fusion-tables, infowindow

I can't seem to hide the infowindow that Google Fusion Tables create when visualize my table.  I also use this tag in the configure info window panel

Also, how do I disable the pan and zoom options that are built in the map?

```
<div class="googft-info-window" style="display: none !important;">
```

I only wanted to hide the infowindow when a user clicks on the map icon.

My map is rendered via an iframe tag in my WordPress page.

```
    <div id="map-canvas">
    <iframe width="300" height="390" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&amp;q=select+col2+from+1_uhammcozMw1p-6u57R5gs-BG-P4ksDP2kb78kI&amp;h=false&amp;lat=36.66194290626721&amp;lng=-97.37956750000001&amp;z=3&amp;t=1&amp;l=col2"></iframe>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: false,
    scaleControl: false
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
}
</script>
```

I don't have Google's map api in my header since it is a straight embed.

Your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: currently you can't.

Comment: Thanks... is there an alternative way to show only the map marker icons?

Comment: As long as you implement the map via the embedded iframe: **no**. When you embed the map via the javascript-API you only need to set the `clickable`-option of the FusionTablesLayer to `false`.

Comment: Okay. Basically the map is being fed from Fusion Tables. How do I get the correct href from Fusion Tables? Thank you.

Comment: There is no href, you must embed HTML-and JS-code. Go to https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1_uhammcozMw1p-6u57R5gs-BG-P4ksDP2kb78kI#map:id=3 , at the bottom of the **publish**-window(where you also got the code for the iframe) is a link "get HTML and Javascript"...that's the code you need. `layer` ist the FusionTablesLayer, add the mentioned `clickable`-option and set it to `false`

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/tk5pdhvg/